# Draftjs apply inline styling to text programatically

Tags: draftjs

I have the following function

```
 buttonToSelection(){
  const editorState = this.state.editorState;
  var selectionState = editorState.getSelection();
  const newSelection = selectionState.merge({
        anchorOffset: 1,
        focusOffset: 10
  })
  const newEditorState = EditorState.forceSelection(editorState, newSelection);
  this.editorChangeState(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(newEditorState,'STRIKEOUT'));
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is upon clicking a button style the text range between 1 and 10 with STRIKEOUT. The function does that at the moment but also keeps the selection of the text. I just want it to change the styling of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it almost right. But since you've given Draft a new selection (which is appropriate for adding styles using RichUtils) it will try to render that selection. So before calling `editorChangeState`, you have to reset the selection again to its previous value. Here's how it could look (with some overly descriptive variables):

```
buttonToSelection = () => {
  const editorState = this.state.editorState;
  const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();
  const newSelection = selectionState.merge({
    anchorOffset: 1,
    focusOffset: 10
  })
  const editorStateWithNewSelection = EditorState.forceSelection(editorState, newSelection);
  const editorStateWithStyles = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorStateWithNewSelection,'STRIKEOUT')
  const editorStateWithStylesAndPreviousSelection = EditorState.forceSelection(
    editorStateWithStyles,
    selectionState
  )
  this.editorChangeState(editorStateWithStylesAndPreviousSelection);
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uLqmwjp/2/) showing it in action. Make sure you have written at least 11 characters in the editor before clicking the button though, or it'll break.